# Evolution - how to connect to an exchange server?

Tags: exchange, evolution

I remember using Evolution to connect to an exchange server a long time ago.  Since then, I installed Evolution along with the exchange server plugin and am trying to get it setup to no avail.

I have the OWA URL and can login there just fine; however, I cannot appear to authenticate with it in Evolution.

Any ideas as to what I might be missing?  My email address and username do not match up, but I didn't believe that to be an issue.  I entered the username I use to login via OWA as well as my email address.

Comment: What version of Exchange are you trying to connect to now? Can the system admin provide any assistance?  Event log errors, etc.

Comment: I think it is 2007, eh, it isn't supported, so I am on my own here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook 2007 is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used, I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 connecting to Exchange 2003.

```
Domain\Username
-https://servername/exchange
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the OWA url from the dialog box that requests your password when you first sign-in to MS Outlook Web Access via your browser. And like slhck said, use the whole address, from the protocol ("http:" or "https:") to the port if it's provided (":80" in my case).